# What URL to use to authenticate with IBMs Maximo REST API

Tags: rest, maximo, websphere

I am trying to connect IBM's Maximo REST API described here; https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_authentication

I have a licensed account for Maximo, but I can't find the URL to hit to start making the Auth call and successive calls.

Anyone know how I can find it or what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The Public URI for OSLC is available in the System Properties application. Check the value of mxe.oslc.restwebappurl in Maximo.

Comment: From the Start Center I went to "System Configuration->Platform Configuration->System Properties" and found 64 Property Names starting with "mxe". None of them were "mxe.oslc.restwebappurl".  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: That is where I would expect it to be, but that count seems low. Maybe there is some sort of data restriction - you could check from the database if you have access (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/checking-maximo-properties-sql-statement). I'd also try in your browser from either the loginpage or within maximo to change the url after /maximo/ to /maximo/oslc/ and see if you can access the API root since the URL is usually the same. Lastly check to see if you have mxe.oslc.webappurl in system properties

Comment: I'm turning up blanks at all fronts. I don't have DB access, mxe.oslc.webappurl is not in my system properties and changing the URL as suggested didn't work.  Is REST API access something that is added after getting a license account?

Comment: Licenses in Maximo are on a per-user basis and related to how many modules (groups of applications) a user has access to and shouldn't affect this. What version of Maximo are you using?